# How to structure a firebase DB in order to allow users to favorite products, to minimize cost pricewise and timewise?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to understand how best to structure my db to accommodate a user favoriting a product. 
I'm conflicted between the following two approaches. For context my products are in the realtime DB and my user model and favorite model are in Firestore.

1.
When the user favorites an item, create a new favorite object in Firestore with the productID and userID. This would mean to get the products with the highest number of favorites I would have to sort the favorite objects by product id and count the highest. And to return a users list of favorites I would have to sort the list of all favorites by the usersID. - I could always stick the favorite item in something like alogia (which I am using for full text search) for faster sorting, but then I am updating twice and storing twice.

2.
When the user favorites an item, I increment the "number of favorites" variable on a product and add the productID to the user's list of favorites. This would make getting the products with the highest number of favorites easier but make, favoriting and unfavoriting a product more complicated.

What is the recommend approach with firebase? The first is approach is more a relational DB solution and seems like it would be expensive, I know they recommend keeping firebase db flat. What would be the cheaper option time wise and cost wise for firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach will be some kind of expensive in Firestore because for every product that is marked as a favorite you'll be charged with one document write and when you rank them, you'll be charged with one read operation for each "Favorite" object that is returned by your query.

The second approach sounds much better because you filter the products bases on a property. "Favoriting" and "unfavoriting" is not so complicated as you might think. If you are talking about a list, you can simply add and remove elements, as explained in the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).

Comment: Hi Alex, I'm curious should this be the general protocol with most info tied to an object that I am looking to rank? For example, something like sales, which would be tied to a user who made the sale and product that was sold. In a relational DB you would just create an entity for sales and then manage relationships between the two. But if understand your recommendation if I am looking to rank the products by lowest/highest sale price I should embed the sales in the user and product objects respectively. That just feels wrong/extraneous? I could rank sale objects and then pull the product.

Comment: *should this be the general protocol with most info tied to an object that I am looking to rank?* Only as long as the data fit in the maximum 1MiB quota. If you need to check the size against the limit and stay safe, try [FirestoreDocument-Android](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreDocument-Android/tree/master/firestore-document). *In a relational DB you would just create an entity for sales and then manage relationships between the two.* Things in NoSQL are quite different.

Comment: Gotcha so as long as I can stay under the quota its just drill deeper and if I have to write to two models, as oppose to creating new ones?

Comment: Usually, we create a list or an array with the same type of objects. It will also work with different once. So you should choose to use one or the other solution according to your app's use-case and queries you intend to perform.

Comment: Since you are suggesting writing to two documents (user and product) for any shared object would it make more sense to use the realtime db, since firestore charges on read and write where as realtime charges on amount of data stored and transferred. I'm looking at dealing with over 50,000 products. Or using some combination of the two?

Comment: Without knowing the use-case of your app, I cannot recommend anything. What I can only say, that both are working very well together. If you need more information, please post a new question, so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Understood I created a new question, I appreciate the quick responses. Thanks!